# Protecting Elements From Unspecific CSS

Tags: css, iframe

We're currently having to write some widgets that are going to be embedded on various pages. As far as I know, I have two possible options to protect these widgets from loose CSS rules (e.g. a general `p { background-color: red }` for example). These are:

1. Using a reset stylesheet to ensure all CSS properties for the widget elements are set to known defaults. Using a CSS preprocessor like Less, this can be simple enough:

   ```
   html body #myWidgetID {
     .resetCSSMixin();
   }
   ```
2. Embedding the element into an `iframe` much like suggested on [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/).

Option 1 is a known entity to me. It's not pretty but it'll work. Option 2 I'm not too sure about. Would a large amount of iframes slow the page down? We now a lot of our sites will be visited on old hardware & slow internet speeds. We also need to support old IE 8 - Could there be browser compatibility issues? We certainly can't use the newer iframe attributes.

Can anyone suggest any reasons why I **shouldn't** go with option 2? It sounds like the nicer option, but I'd like a little more guidance before making the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iframes` are a very old feature, so IE8 support is not an issue. The main difference is that an iframe loads a separate document into a frame. This will have a couple of effects:

- The widget is loaded in a separate request. It will need its own HTML page, so you will have an extra HTTP request, and more data that needs to be transferred.
- Still, initial page load might even be faster, because the page can be displayed before the widget is loaded.
- An iframe is a boundary. Pages in the iframe cannot modify elements outside of the iframe. This can be an advantage (3rd party banners/widgets that must not have access due to security risks) or a disadvantage (if you want your own widget to have access to the parent).
- Because it is a separate page, it has its own set of CSS and is not in any way (apart from width/height) affected by the parent page. This can be a advantage or a disadvantage as well. You have complete control of the looks of your widget, but it's hard to give the users/implementors of your widget any possibility to do some additional styling.

Comment: Base IE8 support isn't a problem but I wouldn't have access to things like the use `sandbox` attribute (http://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-sandbox). So wondering if there's anything there that'll bite me later on.

Comment: The sandbox attribute indeed isn't supported in IE8 and 9, but it is only used to impose *extra* restrictions for the content running in the iframe. With an iframe, the isolation level is already much greater than without, so if you're still doubting between option 1 and option 2, support for `sandbox` is not an argument. Also, IE8 users should upgrade, they know their browser is old and has potential security risks (which is not your problem, since you are the builder rather than the consumer of these widgets).

Answer (score 0):

If you care about a CSS property, you will style your widget element with that property either using a more specific rule in the stylesheet or in the style DOM attribute. Either way, it will override loose selectors.

If you don't care about a CSS property, there is no point in resetting it, and you should probably allow it to be themed.